# Using modules from a specific excel file in files generated from said specific one

Tags: excel, vba, module

*Tl;dwtr: General file with macro's, one to create duplicate (a Project), one to send automated mail to request stuff. Last one opens general file and is not using the duplicated in which I clicked said macro.*

In my work I create loads of 'Projects' from one general excel sheet. These projects have specified information stored in them. At the moment I can make a duplicate form the general file en store this with names dates info etc.

Problem being, I wrote a macro in the general file, which uses the specified info and sends automated emails to request some type of file bases on the info. Now when I do this (use the macro **inside the duplicated file**) it opens the general file and uses the leftover info which is still there at the moment.

My guess is that the modules are somehow linked to a certain xls file, but im not sure nor experienced enough to figure it out. I hope some of you can help me out.

Comment: I don't think this complies with [Minimap, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) What you posted is just a guess-work for us. Try to be a bit more specific and create a way to reproduce the issue

Comment: If you don't understand what your code is doing, debug it (use F8) and check what is going on. Especially check when & why your general file is opened.

Comment: @Rawrplus While working on the Testcode to reproduce the problem I found that when using custom macro-assigned ribbons were the problem here. When calling the module from the ribbon it opens the general file, but when done via a button it somehow does not. I'll try to be more specific in the future, Thanks for the reply.